# how to get a html string with url and turn it into json?

Tags: javascript

My url return a number which I want to get the number with javascript/jquery and display on another html file. Here is my code. It just give blank result.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://chainz.cryptoid.info/xmg/api.dws?q=getbalance&a=9LMTFV9AmWFYdVywcaWzr8VayMJJuSVX2d",

    JSON.parse(url)
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(typeof data); // -- Object
      var json = data;
      $('#data').html(json);    
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your URL returns plain number not json.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more specific question. The data you mention is object mean you need to read json object format (e.g.{data1:abc, data2:xyz}) then you only can display the format you want.

After that you may try this

```
$("#data").html(JSON.stringify(json));
```